# How to assign a value to a double bracketed expression in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Specifically, how can I rewrite the following example of dot syntax to the equivalent bracket syntax:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"This is a cell";
```

I thought it would look something like this:

```
[[cell textLabel] text: @"this is a cell"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A read-write property is composed of two methods - a getter and a setter.

The name of the getter corresponds to the name of the property. The name of the setter is prefixed with `set`; the first letter of the property is capitalized:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: @"this is a cell"];
```